# Proving the sum rule

Tags: calculus

The question is:

Show that if each of $f$ and $g$ is a function and $S(x) = f(x) + g(x)$, then $S’(x) = f’(x) + g’(x)$.

Could I use the limit formula:

$\lim_{x\to a} [f(x)+g(x)] = \lim_{x\to a} f(x) + \lim_{x\to a} g(x)$

I have the option of presenting this problem in front of the class but I’m worried I will not be able to explain it because I still don’t understand how to work the problem out. Do you have any tips to get me started?

Comment: Limit of sum can be rewritten as sum of limits.

Comment: @Ella The [Proof of Sum Rule of Differentiation](https://www.mathdoubts.com/derivative-sum-rule-proof/) site has several different proofs of this, plus some discussion about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go by definition:
$$f'(x)=\lim_{x_0\to0}\frac{f(x+x_0)-f(x)}{x_0}$$Thus, if $S(x)=f(x)+g(x)$, then$$S'(x)=\lim_{x_0\to0}\frac{S(x_0+x)-S(x)}{x_0}=\lim_{x_0\to0}\frac{f(x_0+x)-f(x)}{x_0}+\lim_{x_0\to0}\frac{g(x_0+x)-g(x)}{x_0}=f'(x)+g'(x)$$